# Eclipse CDT - Output - when using vs compiler not helpful

Tags: c++, eclipse, cross-platform

I use eclipse CDT (Juno release) and I've been trying out to be able to see the kind of error output when compiling as we have in Visual Studio.

Instead "Problems" view seems very limited in making us see the compiler errors (using same compiler as Visual Studio).

A simple example. If you have a simple typo

```
typedef std::function(void(int)) Func;
```

VS Output shows immediately:

```
    error C2955: 'std::function' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(554) : see declaration of 'std::function'
```

By comparison, using same compiler under CDT I get errors in completely different lines of code, most of it in the area where the wrongly defined typedef is used not in the original place. Is it possible at least to see the "raw compiler output" in a different window in order to have a clue as to what is going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For compiler output, you have to check the **Console** tab. It's one of the tabs placed to the right of the **Problems** tab you are on.

Comment: The wired thing is that the console only shows that compiler was called on that file and build time but no other output.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe you're missing a compiler option? And when you get "errors in completely different lines of code", you want to look at the *last* error, the one down the list in the **Problems** tab. Can you try that with your typo?

Comment: I can go through errors in the "Problems" just that they not point to the line with the typo. Looking at the compiler output from VS compared to eclipse you would say there are different programs/compilers which is not the case

Comment: But you do get multiple lines. Does the last line point to the real error? That's how it works in my Eclipse (but I'm on Linux)

Comment: something happened to my console output I think because I used to see issues there before

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18745/discussion-between-ghita-and-alestanis)

Comment: Solved. There was an issue with my environment variables related to VS11 that eclipse did not see. As soon as I restarted eclipse from a command prompt where VS "stuff" is defined I see raw compiler output in Console.